# Graph View- X axis not ral-time Refresh - Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-graphview

I'm using Graph View to track and display some numbers in real time.
The problem is that after 80 seconds the x axis is not updated and the size change is performed after 40 seconds from [0-80] to [0-200].
Is there a way to change Xaxis every time a new number after 80 seconds will be tracked?
this is my code:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;
private double LastXPoint=2; 

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        GraphView graph= (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {

        });
    graph.addSeries(series);
    graph.getViewport().setMaxX(400);

    DatiRealTime();
}


private final void DatiRealTime() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            LastXPoint++;
            series.appendData(new DataPoint(LastXPoint,plotRRG), false, 300);
            DatiRealTime();

        }
    }, 500);

}
```

[image]

How could I achive it? 
thanks in andvance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling your issue is because of calling DatiRealTime inside the run method. Change the method and use the handler instead:

```
private void DatiRealTime() {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            LastXPoint++;
            series.appendData(new DataPoint(LastXPoint, plotRRG), false, 300);
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope that helped you.